# Jquery slider does not work on iPad works fine on browser

Tags: jquery, slider

I have got tutorial of Jquery slider it works on mac or pc browser but it does not work on iPad device  here is the link

http://loopj.com/jquery-simple-slider/demo.html

Comment: Try this: http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Answer (score 1):

This will be because jQuery Simple Slider doesn't support touch event (i.e. no mouse) natively. My suggestion would be trying to find a slider library that supports both mouse and touch events.

Or, you could also try and use something like [touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/), as this will simulate mouse events on touch.

I've used this successfully a few times, but it will be a matter of trying and seeing if this actually solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the slider that is known to work crossbrowser-crossplatform.

I'd use jquery-ui slider: http://jqueryui.com/slider/

And patch: https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch#readme